# I need to copy only symlinks from within multiple subfolders under a parent folder to another folder maintaining relative path information in symlinks

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, symlink, file-transfer

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and i have a lot of files under multiple subfolders under a parent folder. I need to copy only symlinks from within these subfolders to another folder maintaining the source folder structure. I need to retain them as it is with *exactly same relative path information* so that when they are in a new destination folder they still will continue to behave same as in source folder(destination folder has same folders/files as in source).

**This is what I have:**

Source/file1

Source/folder1/file2

Source/folder1/symlink1 -> ./file2 

Source/folder2/symlink2 -> ../file1

**This is what I need** (symlinks will be ultimately moved to a folder where all files in source will be present in same folder structure)

Destination\folder1\symlink1 -> ./file2 

Destination\folder2\symlink2 -> ../file1

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried these below already

```
find ./ -type l | xargs -I % cp -va % Destination/
Result: all symlinks get copied to destination folder but they lose the source folder structure.

find . -type l | xargs -i cp {} Destination{}

Result: cp: cannot create regular file 'Destination./tools/i18n-uitext/node_modules/istanbul-lib-source-maps/node_modules/.bin/rimraf': No such file or directory
```

Here (below) are some of the symlinks i have in source folder.

Listed below symlinks using command  `find ./ -type l -print0 | xargs -0 ls -plah` from within the source directory. I am intending to copy these symlinks to another directory where they need to maintain this same folder structure.

Note: The source directory is a CI machines workspace folder on one server and the destination directory is a folder outside this workspace folder where i need to copy these symlinks and folders containing them into.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1   19 Jul  4 18:08 ./integrations/link_adyen_v20_1_3/node_modules/.bin/_mocha -> ../mocha/bin/_mocha
lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 Jul  4 18:08 ./integrations/link_adyen_v20_1_3/node_modules/.bin/acorn -> ../acorn/bin/acorn
lrwxrwxrwx 1   19 Jul  4 18:08 ./integrations/link_adyen_v20_1_3/node_modules/.bin/atob -> ../atob/bin/atob.js

lrwxrwxrwx 1   19 Jul  4 18:05 ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -> ../mocha/bin/_mocha
lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 Jul  4 18:05 ./node_modules/.bin/acorn -> ../acorn/bin/acorn
lrwxrwxrwx 1   19 Jul  4 18:05 ./node_modules/.bin/atob -> ../atob/bin/atob.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1   32 Jul  4 18:05 ./node_modules/.bin/autoprefixer -> ../autoprefixer/bin/autoprefixer

lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 Jul  4 18:05 ./node_modules/@babel/compat-data/node_modules/.bin/semver -> ../semver/bin/semver
lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 Jul  4 18:05 ./node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/.bin/semver -> ../semver/bin/semver

lrwxrwxrwx 1   22 Jul  4 18:05 ./node_modules/caniuse-api/node_modules/.bin/browserslist -> ../browserslist/cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1   23 Jul  4 18:05 ./node_modules/core-js-compat/node_modules/.bin/semver -> ../semver/bin/semver.js

lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 Jul  4 18:08 ./tools/i18n-uitext/node_modules/.bin/semver -> ../semver/bin/semver
lrwxrwxrwx 1   21 Jul  4 18:08 ./tools/i18n-uitext/node_modules/.bin/uuid -> ../uuid/dist/bin/uuid
lrwxrwxrwx 1   18 Jul  4 18:08 ./tools/i18n-uitext/node_modules/.bin/which -> ../which/bin/which
lrwxrwxrwx 1   20 Jul  4 18:08 ./tools/i18n-uitext/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/.bin/mkdirp -> ../mkdirp/bin/cmd.js
lrwxrwxrwx 1   16 Jul  4 18:08 ./tools/i18n-uitext/node_modules/fstream/node_modules/.bin/rimraf -> ../rimraf/bin.js
```

Answer (score 0):

People don't use it very much but the legacy utility `cpio` works very well with input from `find` as long as the names aren't too strange (eg. shouldn't contain newlines):

```
(cd src && find -type l | cpio -o) | (cd dest && cpio -d -i)
```

Some implementations (eg. busybox) require archive format to be specified:

```
(cd src && find -type l | cpio -o -H newc) | (cd dest && cpio -d -i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have `cp` from GNU core utils, try this command:

```
cd /path/to/source && find -type l -exec cp -P --parents {} /path/to/destination \;
```